# ClearQuest query - how to get XML output

Tags: clearquest

I have the following ClearQuest query:
https://anst-tg2.com/cqweb/#/CQschema/ACP/QUERY/79138761&noframes=true&format=HTML

How can I modify it in order to get an XML file as output rather than HTML? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to use OSLC instead of the REST API. You can find documentation here:

https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/CqOslcV2

Note the following excerpt from the above-mentioned link:

```
ALERT! While "REST URI" wizard works well for shortcuts, we recommend you
use OSLC instead to access ClearQuest data in other formats such as XML."
```

However, if you still want to use RESTAPI, you can get XML if you follow the instructions here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21445081